# Google scatter chart legend - remove line through dot

Tags: r, google-visualization, googlevis

This is what the legend looks like:

[image]

I want the last 3 series to show up as points, and I want the line through the middle of those dots to go away. Is there a way to do that in series= or legend= options?

Answer (score 0):

you want to use something like this

```
+ scale_colour_manual(values = c("purple", "green", "blue", "yellow", "magenta"),
                   guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(
                     linetype = c("solid", "solid",rep("blank", 3)),
                     shape = c(NA,NA, rep(16, 3)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, it's fairly intuitive. `lineWidth: 0` in the series options will get rid of the line.

```
gvisComboChart(df, 
    options = list(
        series = "[{type:'points', lineWidth: 0}]"
    )
)
```